# how to navigate to a new screen inside tabs in react-navigation 4

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So this is the case. I have let's say login screen which is tab-based, one tab is login and other one is register. I also have a "Forgot password" button. So when I press forgot password button I want to go to a "forgot Password" screen which is inside tab navigation and has that "back" button in its header.
how can I do that ?

here is a photo
I need to change the current screen white bottom tab still is shown but the top tab is not going to show until I press the back button
[image]

[image]
in second photo what I need to happen is shown by green arrow and what I get is shown by the red one. (look at the bottom tab in two different results)

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: i have found the way, maybe - I need a stack navigator inside a bottom tab navigator and I have created that but when I navigate to the new screen, new screen takes whole screen instead of being wrapped inside bottom tab navigator. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab

Comment: You need to nest stack nav inside your bottom navs last tab button. I can help you with React navigation v5 but in React navigation 4 there are few limitations.

Comment: I did that but the result was the one with a red arrow

Comment: This doc will help you but it is for react navigation v5 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

Comment: Keep in mind all the stack screens in which you want the bottom bar to be visible should be inside the bottom tab screen. A snack demo from you will be easier for me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this document:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/tab-based-navigation/#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab in **A stack navigator for each tab** paragraph

and this the implementation :

```
const ProfilePostStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Profile: {screen: Profile},
    PostsDetails: {screen: ProfilePosts}
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

**Profile** screen is a bottom-tab containing 5 different tabs and **postsDetails** in a single screen

then when I navigated to PostsDetails

Comment: Yes, I was saying the same thing. Glad that you fixed it.